# adsheet warning

Tags: ios, iad

can anyone explain the meaning/reason of this adsheet warning please?

```
Nov 23 09:24:06 unknown AdSheet[256] <Warning>: AdSheet running for 59.992 seconds with 1 clients and 1 assertions [banner:1]: info.company.app (State: Foreground Running) (Background: 0, no timer) has 1 banners: 0xee74b00:EDFD972C-2C31-45A6-A57C-F129F8D0CB97 (created 2011-11-23 17:23:44 +0000) [Visible: never] [In Window: YES]
```

it repeats every 20 seconds (in the log) and increments the "running for xx.xx seconds" with 20 seconds each time.

It comes up in the log with my iAd supported application and regardless whether the Test Advertisement is loaded or not.

after I kill the application it continues two or three times with:

```
Nov 23 09:33:06 unknown AdSheet[256] <Warning>: AdSheet running for 599.993 seconds with 0 clients and 0 assertions []:
```

and then it stops

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the `[Visible: never]` has to do with the warning. Are you sure your AdSheet is visible and entirely on the screen? Did you by any chance accidently add a copy of the AdSheet to your viewController in IB that you don't know of? You should keep in mind that Ads should appear in the foreground.

Comment: that's the thing. I don't know what AdSheet is and what/why it is trying to tell me. I understand the didFailToReceiveAdWithError or bannerViewDidLoadAd messages (when I get them) but not these AdSheet ones. When the app receives a Test Add, it displays it properly on the screen.

Comment: same here didnt used anything related to adsheet in my app. Still got this error. Is any external library calling it ? or its a xcode bug ?